# What does "taking a standard" mean?

Tags: expressions

The following sentence is from an essay by Thomas Reid:

> Suppose a brave officer to have been flogged when a boy at school for robbing an orchard, to have taken a standard from the enemy in his first campaign, and to have been made a general in advanced life.

What does he mean by "taking a standard"?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us what research you have done before asking this question. It is a good question, but you are expected to say what work you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the noun "standard" in sense 4 of the [Oxford English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/standard): "A military or ceremonial flag carried on a pole or hoisted on a rope."

To take the standard of the enemy after a battle indicates your total victory. In ancient Rome, for example, to have your legion's own standard captured was one of the greatest shames that could come upon your legion.